# boost date parse 29FEB

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

There is some problem with datetime parsing, that I have no idea about great workaround.

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

namespace dt = boost::gregorian;

dt::date parse_date(const std::string& msg, const std::string& format)
{
   std::stringstream s(msg);
   dt::date_input_facet * f = new dt::date_input_facet();
   if (format.empty())
   {
      f->set_iso_format();
   }
   else
   {
      f->format(format.c_str());
   }
   std::locale l(std::locale(), f);
   s.imbue(l);
   dt::date result;
   s >> result;
   return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string v = "0229";
    auto p = parse_date(v, "%m%d");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b4e29e23b27397c)

Problem is, that default year in datetime parser is `1400`, that is not leap, so there is no 29 february in this year. The main question is of course why `1400` year is default and not any leap year, anyway I need some nice workaround, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "why" question is not particularly relevant¹. It's just the way it works. The key is that you  know what is stopping you from parsing it.

I'd just do the easy thing, below, or [just write a tiny spirit parser (`int_parser<unsigned char, 10, 2, 2>` twice)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/752c3ab1fdd5b4e3) and construct a `ptime` directly).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5b4cf9e7b591f1e)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

namespace dt = boost::gregorian;

dt::date parse_date_mmdd(const std::string &msg) {
    std::stringstream s("2000" + msg);
    dt::date_input_facet *f = new dt::date_input_facet();
    f->format("%Y%m%d");

    std::locale l(std::locale(), f);
    s.imbue(l);
    dt::date result;
    s >> result;

    return result;
}

int main() {
    const std::string v = "0229";
    auto p = parse_date_mmdd(v);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
2000-Feb-29
```

---

¹ The answer likely centers on *"there is no data type associated with `DayOfYear`"* as a DayOfMonth tuple (there is no use for it in a date handling library). So you'll always have to decide on a contextual year. Like you'll always have to decide on what timezone to interpret a posix time in. Or even which calendar model to use.

Comment: There is a partial_date but sadly it does not respect the format string he uses. If "2902" instead of "0229" would work, he could use [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c53d94f3c5e1f44).

Comment: Good find, @cv_and_he. I wonder how useful `partial_date` is for other tasks (will have a look one day). Here's [the X3 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/752c3ab1fdd5b4e3) for completeness

Comment: Interesting. Of course I have idea about just add year, but I don't like that way, but probably it's the best. And it's very interesting solution, using partial_date.